# Add T-SQL in maintenance plan in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, maintenance-plan

How can I set a T-SQL statement as a part of a maintenance plan in SQL Server?
Since I can see options of backup etc but not the possibility of adding T-SQL

Comment: is there a possibility of using SQL server agent jobs..??

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why you are looking to set up a maintenance plan.But, the alternate approach would be to set up a SQL server agent job to execute your T-SQL statements (which can be put together as procedures) and schedule it accordingly.

At the same time, you can execute SQL jobs through maintenance plans as well. This page will also help you : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/maintenance-plans/use-the-maintenance-plan-wizard?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 1):

First I connected to my SQL server using SQL Server Management Studio.

I went to the node `Management`, right-clicked the subnode `Maintenance Plans` and created a new maintenance plan called `Test`. My maintenance plan automatically got a subplan called `Subplan_1`. I just kept it and saved the maintenance plan.

Next, I went to the node `SQL Server Agent`, opened the subnode `Jobs` and double-clicked node `Test.Subplan_1`. It had a job step called `Subplan_1`. Double-clicking that job step opened the job step's properties. There I could choose the type `Transact-SQL script (T-SQL)` and enter my SQL code.

I did not encounter any problems. I used SQL Server 2017, but I am pretty sure it works about the same way in earlier versions of SQL Server...

Edit:

Like sabhari karthik commented and answered, it is very well possible to just create a new job with SQL Server Agent and schedule that job. So perhaps you do not need a maintenance plan at all. But if you do use maintenance plans (or are required to use and/or edit existing maintenance plans), it might be just the case that a maintenance plan's subplan automatically gets a related SQL Server Agent job. But I am not sure. I have never configured and used any maintenance plans before. I'm just a software developer, not a DBA.

Edit 2:

I see in the Maintenance Plan Wizard that there is an option to execute a SQL Server Agent Job as a maintenance task as well. But it seems you need to create that SQL Server Agent Job first.

Comment: Double-clicking that job step opened the job step's properties. Still i cant see any options to add T-SQL  General ,Steps , Schedules ,Alerts,Notifications etc are the options available while double clicking the Job

Comment: You can click the page/node "Steps" in the left pane of the "Job Properties" screen. Then it shows the job steps of that job in a list in the right pane. If you create a new step or open (doubleclick) an existing step, a screen with the step details is opened. There you can specify that the job step's type (for example "Transact-SQL script (T-SQL)".